# Hadoop Source Jars from maven

Tags: maven, hadoop

I went to the following location for the hadoop version 1.2.1

```
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1
```

There are no source jars.  I have also tried to download via sbt

```
   sbt update-classifiers
```

and maven

```
mvn dependency:sources

The following files have NOT been resolved:

org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:sources:1.2.1:compile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With later versions of Hadoop, the sources became available, so updating to the latest version should help nowadays, e.g. version 2.7.1 has them at http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.1/ and Maven/Gradle should find them automatically now.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop jars doesn't bundle source, You will get hadoop tar ball from the below apache repository which contains source and binaries. Source files are located inside src directory.

https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-1.2.1/